# png file shows bluish image when using plt.imshow()

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to plot a png file using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` but it's showing a bluish image(see below). It works for jpeg file but not for png.

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('apple_logo.png')
im.save('test.png') #test.png is same as original
data = np.array(im)
print(data) 
plt.imshow(data) #shows a bluish image of the logo
```

The image i'm using:

[image: apple_logo image i'm using]

bluish image:

[image: bluish image of the apple_logo]

Python 3.8.2
matplotlib 3.3.0
Pillow 7.2.0
numpy 1.19.0
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original PNG image is an indexed PNG file.  That is, it has a palette (i.e. a lookup table for the colors), and the array of data that makes up the image is an array of indices into the lookup table.  When you convert `im` to a numpy array with `data = np.array(im)`, `data` is the array of indices into the palette, instead of the array of actual colors.

Use the [`convert()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) method before passing the image through `numpy.array`:

```
data = np.array(im.convert())
```

Comment: thanks! it worked. But can you tell me how does png files' array store which pixel is transparent? because when I do `print(data)` the array contains arrays of just 3 elements like `[255 255 255]` only for rgb colors same as jpg files.